# problem of calculating month to date revenue for each department in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I queried one data frame like this:

```
Select 
Date, 
Department, 
cumu_revenue_yr, 
LAG(cumu_revenue_yr,1) OVER (
                PARTITION BY Department
                ORDER BY Date) as previous_cumu_revenue_yr,
(cumu_revenue_yr - previous_cumu_revenue_yr) as 1day_revenue
from dmf_dbo.revenue
```

[image]

cumu_revenue_yr is the cumulative revenues from first day of year to the current day.

However, if I want to have one additional column to show how much I earn from beginning of each month until now (current cumu_revenue_yr - previous month-end cumu_revenue_yr), how can I do that?

I try to do something like:

```
Select 
Date, 
Department, 
cumu_revenue_yr, 
LAG(cumu_revenue_yr, 1) OVER (
                PARTITION BY Department
                ORDER BY Date) as previous_cumu_revenue_yr,
(cumu_revenue_yr - previous_cumu_revenue_yr) as 1day_revenue,
LAG(cumu_revenue_yr, Day(Date)) OVER (
                PARTITION BY Department
                ORDER BY Date) as previous_monthend_cumu_revenue,
(cumu_revenue_yr - previous_monthend_cumu_revenue) as whole_month_revenue,,
from dmf_dbo.revenue
```

But there are two problems:

1. LAG() only accept positive int in second argument.
2. The time series is business day. In other words, there will be no data records in weekend or holiday. So, using LAG(cumu_revenue_yr, Day(Date)) cannot help me extract the correct data.

Anyone has any suggestion?
The final data frame should look like

[image]

Comment: lag only accepts positive ints, because the ORDER BY in the window function can be set to ASC or DESC, which will change the direction of the LAG output.


For the weekends, you can filter the result set such that only weekdays are shown by means of DatePart, though that's kneejerk thought and could cause performance issues depending on how you implement it.


For holidays, you're best off with a reference table to filter against, such that dates in rows returned do not exist in the reference table of holidays.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. DDL and usable data help us help you. Pictures of data don't.

Comment: @HABO Thanks for the info. will improve the way I raise questions next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 queries.  The first query is how I think the first set of data was returned.  The second query adds the monthly running cumulative total of 1day_revenue

```
/* Query */
Select [Date], Department, cumu_revenue_yr, 
       (cumu_revenue_yr - LAG(cumu_revenue_yr, 1) OVER (
                              PARTITION BY Department
                              ORDER BY Date)) as [1day_revenue]
from dmf_dbo.revenue;
```

[EDIT] The LAG function runs in a CTE.  The CTE is then accessed to calculate the SUM OVER the year, month partitioning.

```
/* Query with SUM() OVER */
;with lag_cte([Date], Department, cumu_revenue_yr, [1day_revenue]) as (
    Select [Date], Department, cumu_revenue_yr, 
           (cumu_revenue_yr - LAG(cumu_revenue_yr, 1) OVER (
                                  PARTITION BY Department
                                  ORDER BY Date))
    from dmf_dbo.revenue)
Select *, sum(cumu_revenue_yr-[1day_revenue]) over 
             (partition by year([Date]), month([Date])
              order by [Date]) as cumu_revenue_month
from lag_cte;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think this is really close to the answer I am searching for. However, I got an error "Invalid expression near 'LAG'".
I think there might be a problem with statement of sum and over. Do you have idea what might be the reason? I tried several way to modfy the code but still got this error

Comment: Probably can't nest the windowing functions.  I removed the LAG to a CTE then access it from the outer SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` for this:

```
select r2.*, r.cumu_revenue_yr - coalesce(r2.cumu_revenue_yr, 0) as mtd
from dmf_dbo.revenue r outer apply
     (select top (1) r2.*
      from dmf_dbo.revenue r2
      where r2.department = r.department and
            year(r2.date) = year(r.date) and
            r2.date < datefromparts(year(r.date), month(r.date), 1)
      order by r2.date desc
     ) r2
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. However, due to some reasons, I would prefer the solution which modified the codes in "select" statement than the approach which change the codes after "from" statement.

Comment: @happyhow . . . I really don't understand what you mean with the comment.